# C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 UIのエラー

Tags: c++11, qt5, qt-creator

**Source Code**
http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-gui-programming-with-qt4-9780132354165
**PDF File**
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215458943_C_GUI_programming_with_Qt_4

再びなのですが、`UI`ファイルを作成したとき、（`QtDesigner`で、`GUI`を構築したとき）なのですが、いつも`ui->`で、橙色の波線が引かれ、
 **member Access into incomplete type UI::SortDialog**
という警告文がエディタに表示されます。ヘッダファイルの設定が間違えているのでしょうか。それとも、コンパイラなどが違うからでしょうか。何かご存知の方はお願いいたします。

**sortdialog.cpp**

```
#include "sortdialog.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>


SortDialog::SortDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SortDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);#here
    ui->secondaryGroupBox->hide();#here
    ui->tertiaryGroupBox->hide();#here
    layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
    setColumnRange('A','Z');

}
void SortDialog::setColumnRange(QChar first,QChar last)
{
    ui->primaryColumnCombo->clear();#here
    ui->secondaryColumnCombo->clear();#here
    ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->clear();#here

    ui->secondaryColumnCombo->addItem(tr("None"));#here
    ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->addItem(tr("None"));#here

    ui->primaryColumnCombo->setMinimumSize(
                ui->secondaryColumnCombo->sizeHint());#here
    QChar ch = first;
    while (ch <= last){
        ui->primaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));#here
        ui->secondaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));#here
        ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));#here
        ch = ch.unicode() + 1;
    }
}
SortDialog::~SortDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**sortdialog.h**

```
#ifndef SORTDIALOG_H
#define SORTDIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtUiTools/QUiLoader>
namespace Ui {
class SortDialog;
}
class SortDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SortDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SortDialog();
    void setColumnRange(QChar first,QChar last);
private:
    Ui::SortDialog *ui;
};
#endif // SORTDIALOG_H
```

**sortdialog.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>SortDialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="SortDialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>341</width>
    <height>319</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Sort</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Primary Key</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="primaryColumnCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="primaryOrderCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>62</width>
          <height>13</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1" rowspan="2">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="okButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>OK</string>
       </property>
       <property name="default">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="cancelButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Cancel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="moreButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&amp;More</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>9</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Secondary Kye</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="secondaryColumnCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="secondaryOrderCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>116</width>
          <height>13</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Tertiary Key</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="tertiaryColumnCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="tertiaryOrderCombo">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>116</width>
          <height>13</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>okButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>SortDialog</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>274</x>
     <y>37</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>105</x>
     <y>102</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>cancelButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>SortDialog</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>296</x>
     <y>66</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>177</x>
     <y>108</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>moreButton</sender>
   <signal>toggled(bool)</signal>
   <receiver>groupBox_2</receiver>
   <slot>setVisible(bool)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>311</x>
     <y>99</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>159</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>moreButton</sender>
   <signal>toggled(bool)</signal>
   <receiver>groupBox_3</receiver>
   <slot>setVisible(bool)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>327</x>
     <y>111</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>209</x>
     <y>258</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

---

**実行環境**
qtcreator 4.7
qt 5.9.6
c++11
**コンパイラ**:

`Desktop_Qt_5_9_6_MSVC2017_64bit`

Comment: sortdialog.uiから生成されるはずの`ui_sortdialog.h`ファイルを読み込んでいる部分が見当たりませんね。`Ui::SortDialog`クラスの定義本体がは`ui_sortdialog.h`に作成されるので、それを読み込まないとクラス定義の本体が見つからないまま、そのクラスのメンバーにアクセスしようとしている、と言うことで御記載のエラーになります。(`Ui::SortDialog`クラスと、namespace無しで定義されている`SortDialog`クラスとは別物。)`#include "ui_sortdialog.h"`を入れておくと何かのエラーが出るとかで削ってしまわれたのでしょうか?(だとすると、ビルド方法が間違っていると言うことになります。)

Comment: その通りでした。エラーを避けようとして消してしまったところまでもがあっています。インクルードしたら、`ui->`に関するエラーはなくなりました。ありがとうございます。おかげさまでエラーは32から25へ減りました。

Comment: これを解決してもまだ他の問題があるのですか、早く解決できるといいですね。ところで自己回答していただいた中で`sortdialog.h`はすでに読み込まれているので、`ui_sortdialog.h`ではないでしょうか?

Comment: その通りです。何度もすいません。元々は90以上はあったと思いますが、何とかこれだけ減らしたつもりです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortdialog.cpp`へ`ui_sortdialog.h`のヘッダファイルをインクルードします。
すると`ui->`のエラーは解消します。
解決です。